# ERROR - Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir... Selenium Web Scraping with Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am running a web scraper using selenium and from time to time, I

```
ERROR - Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: %s If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

I know it means selenium can't open a session but how do I resolve this? Should I put in a retry mechanism with an exponential backoff? Is it a bug in selenium?

I don't know but any help in resolving this issue would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ brew install geckodriver
$ pip install -U selenium

firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True

driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities)
driver.get('http://example.com')
```